# Docker bash script wait for container log to contain "done"

Tags: bash, docker

I'm looking to write a bash script that will not progress until the log of a container states "[services.d] done."

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ docker logs container | grep "[services.d] done." ] = "false";
do
    sleep 1
    echo "working..."
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grep will return false if it will not find the string, so try just:

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! docker logs container | grep -q "[services.d] done.";
do
    sleep 1
    echo "working..."
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to modify it a little but it worked after.

Comment: `until docker ... | grep ...; done` Look mah no bang `!` :-)

Comment: If you don't mind losing the working... message, something like this seems simpler:
`docker logs -f container 2>&1 | grep -m 1 '[services.d] done.' `